# random sequence converges to a different value each time

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

I am simulating a random walk. Within each execution, the sequence converges to a fixed number. However, the number to which the sequence converges varies in different executions. Is this still called "the random variable converges?" If so, does it converge in probability / almost surely / in distribution? Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, you are saying you have a sequence of random variables $(X_i)_i$ such that for every $\omega$ in your sample space you have $X_i(\omega)$ converges. In this case you would say that $X_i$ converges, or $X_i$ converges for every $\omega$. This kind of convergence is the strictest amongst the ones you mention. If $X_i$ converges for every $\omega$, then it also converges almost surely, and it also converges in probability, and it also converges in distribution.

Comment: Sorry, I read it wrong originally, the statements are fixed now.